# How to disable focus on slick slider, which causes web page to scroll down to slick slider on load?

Tags: javascript

Page scrolls down to slick slider on load due to Focus on slick slider.

I have tried disabling FocusOnSelect by setting it to false but that makes selection of slick to stop working.

Comment: Can you make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Hi, sorry there didnt get the chance to reply yesterday...

Comment: However, for the solution we ended up using Window.scrollTo(0,0) inside of useEffect after a setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

the solution we ended up using Window.scrollTo(0,0) inside of useEffect after a setTimeout()